# iPhone video play size

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

am developing a iphone app and I have a video in a uiwebview. When I press play the video plays in full screen. Is there a way I can make it so when I press play the video plays in a custom size and not full screen?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can make `UIViewControllerSubClass` that inherit from "`MPMoviePlayerController`" and set it size using `SetFrame`
in the .h

```
-(void) setFrame:(CGRect) frame;
```

and in the .m

```
-(void) setFrame:(CGRect) frame{
    [self.view setFrame:frame];
}
```

so every time you use the `MPMoviePlayerController` you can access the
setframe method such

```
[viewobject setframe:cgrectmake(0,0,250,400)];
```